# How to include own css on wordpress tinymce editor?

Tags: customization, css, tinymce, editor, add-editor-style

I have added some text on tinymce editor on load.
(Every time you click on Add new the tinymce editor load with this text.)

but problem is how to enable css class which are using in default text.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `add_editor_style`

e.g.: functions.php

```
add_editor_style('custom-editor-style.css');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style

Comment: You are Great .

Answer (score 5):

`add_editor_style` is recommended for theme.
You can `mce_css` filter in plugin. The following sample code is from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_css)

```
function plugin_mce_css( $mce_css ) {
  if ( !empty( $mce_css ) )
    $mce_css .= ',';
    $mce_css .= plugins_url( 'editor.css', __FILE__ );
    return $mce_css;
  }
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'plugin_mce_css' );
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing I found worked. Took me half a day on Google, but finally stumbled upon this script that works:

```
function kwh_add_editor_style( $mceInit ) {

  $custom_css = get_theme_mod( 'custom_css' );
  $styles = '.mce-content-body { EDIT YOUR CUSTOM CSS HERE ' . $custom_css . '; }';

  if ( !isset( $mceInit['content_style'] ) ) {
    $mceInit['content_style'] = $styles . ' ';
  } else {
    $mceInit['content_style'] .= ' ' . $styles . ' ';
  }
  return $mceInit;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'kwh_add_editor_style' );
```

[Source](https://www.mattcromwell.com/dynamic-tinymce-editor-styles-wordpress/) of snippet.